# When will iridescence only happen when seen through a mirror-like surface?

Tags: optics, interference

The phenomenon is:

A semi-opaque semi-rigid plastic sheet covers a window, if you see the sheet directly from any direction, there is no iridescence on the sheet. But if you see the sheet through a smooth reflective surface, there is iridescence on the sheet. Tested reflection surfaces are highly reflective ceramic tile/smooth plastic object/phone front panel(which is glass). But **mirror doesn't** show iridescence on the sheet.

The iridescence is on the plastic sheet, not on the window that is not covered or the reflective surface itself (based on the distance of the iridescence from eye and wiping the surface doesn't change the iridescence pattern)

When and how deos this happen? Since it is related to reflection, it may be related to polarization, but how?

Comment: Are you looking at the doubly reflected light source? Or is the sheet illuminated from some other direction?

Comment: @KeithMcClary light source is sun light which come from outside the window and go through the window then the sheet then the reflecting surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing polarization effects.  Light reflected from smooth dielectric surfaces at an angle of about 57 degrees from normal is higjly polarized.  The plastic sheet has slightly different refractive index in different directions, usually because it was stretched during manufacture.  Light passing through the plastic sheet has its polarization rotated according to wavelength and angle.  So the smooth glassy surface *and the surfaces of the plastic film* both act as polarizing filters.  You can get a polarizing filter from a camera store or srom a science hobbiest supply and confirm this.

Comment: True but does not address the issue of how/why you can achieve polarized thruput

Comment: I edited my answer to fill in that blank.

Comment: (1) This has nothing to do with interference? Why the iridescence entry of wiki doesn't mention polarization at all (2) The mirror doesn't create the iridescence because 90% light are reflected by metal?

Comment: The common perception among optics folks is a bit muddled in the areas where polarization and interference overlap conceptually.  Yes, the colors are produced by interference.  Also, yes, the colors are produced by interference.  But for both to make sense you need a really good understanding of interference and polarization.  Not enough room here to teach you.  A good college level optics book has what you need to understand.